# Calculation of an absolute position

Tags: positioning, calculations, textpos

My question is about calculating with the package textpos.

By saving the vertical position of a block of text with zsavepos and calculating the middle of it, I want to position a block of text at the same vertical position.

In the following example, it doesn't seem to work.

Thank you for your answer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{zref-savepos}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}

\zsavepos{begin}
\lipsum[20]
\zsavepos{end}

\begin{textblock*}{2.5cm}[0.5,0.5](2cm,0.5\zposy{begin}sp-0.5\zposy{end}sp)
\noindent \textit{Text that should be centered vertically.}
\end{textblock*}

\begin{textblock*}{2.5cm}[0.5,0.5](2cm,11143907sp)
\noindent \textit{Text approximately properly centered.}
\end{textblock*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1; also because I didn't know before about the `zref` package – that's an _interesting_ thing.

Answer (score 4):

I think there are a couple things going on here.

The first, `\zposy` returns the vertical position as measured from the bottom of the page.    In this next example, I dispense with using the `calc` package and use `\dimexpr` from `e-TeX`.

I believe this will give you the results you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{zref-savepos}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\begin{document}

\zsavepos{begin}
\lipsum[20]
\zsavepos{end}

\begin{textblock*}{2.5cm}[0,0.5](2.5cm,{\dimexpr\paperheight-\zposy{begin}sp+(\zposy{begin}sp-\zposy{end}sp)/2})
  \noindent \textit{Text that should be centered vertically.}
\end{textblock*}

\begin{textblock*}{2.5cm}[0,0.5](\dimexpr\paperwidth-3.5cm,11143907sp)
\noindent $\circ$\textit{Text approximately properly centered.}
\end{textblock*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Incidentally,

```
0.5\zposy{begin}
```

doesn't do what you're expecting it to.  If `\zposy{begin}` is `5`, then `0.5\zposy{begin}` expands to `0.55` not `2.5`.

To calculate have the y-pos, you need to do one of the following:

```
\zposy{begin}/2
```

or

```
\zposy{begin}*\real{0.5}
```

So then to correctly calculate the position using `calc` package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{zref-savepos}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\begin{document}

\zsavepos{begin}
\lipsum[20]
\zsavepos{end}

\begin{textblock*}{2.5cm}[0,0.5](2.5cm,\paperheight-\zposy{begin}sp+\zposy{begin}sp*\real{0.5}-\zposy{end}sp*\real{0.5})
  \noindent \textit{Text that should be centered vertically.}
\end{textblock*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works perfectly as I wanted. I now need adjustments when this concerns maths equations. 

Thank you very much.